# Convert vector<unsigned char> {1,2,3} into string "1-2-3" AS DIGITS

Tags: c#, c++, string, vector, data-conversion

I want to display numbers in a `std::vector<unsigned char>` on a screen, but on its way to the recipient, I need to stuff these numbers into a `std::string`.

Whatever I tried (`atoi`, `reinterpret_cast`, `string.c_str()` ...), gave me either a nonsense, or a letter representation of those original numbers - i.e. their corresponding ascii characters.

So how do I easily (preferably standard method) convert `vector<unsigned char> {1,2,3}` into a `string "1-2-3"`?

In the Original Post (later edited) I mentioned, that I could do that in C# or Java.
Upon the request of πάντα ῥεῖ to provide example in C# or Java, here is a quick Linq C# way:

```
    public static string GetStringFromListNumData<T>(List<T> lNumData)
    {
        // if (typeof(T) != typeof(IConvertible)) throw new ArgumentException("Expecting only types that implement IConvertible !");
        string myString = "";
        lNumData.ForEach(x => myString += x + "-");
        return myString.TrimEnd('-');
    }
```

Comment: `1` and `'1'` are not the same thing.

Comment: How would you have done that in _easy ways_ using C# or Java?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  I just posted C# example, for sure a subject to possible improvements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream):

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v{1,2,3};
std::ostringstream oss;
bool first = true;
for(auto x : v) {
    if(!first) oss << '-'; 
    else first = false;
    oss << (unsigned int)x;
}
std::cout << oss.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: The OP has a `vector<unsigned char>` not a `vector<int>`.

Comment: Absolutely brillant answer ! Here is how I learn C++11/14
Thank you so much !

Comment: @Peter THX, but there's room to improve your question though. May be give a sample as mentioned in my comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I handle that:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v {1, 2, 3};

std::string s; // result

auto sep = ""; // continuation separator
for(auto n: v)
{
    s += sep + std::to_string(n);
    sep = "-"; // change the continuation separator after first element
}

std::cout << s << '\n';
```

The *continuation separator* starts out empty and gets changed after concatenating the first output.

**Output:**

```
1-2-3
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet, another example:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> v{1,2,3};

std::ostringstream str;
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(str, "-"), [](unsigned char c){ return '0' + c;});

std::cout << str.str();
```

[edit]

unfortunately above will add additional trailing `-` symbol, to prevent it - more complicated code is necessary:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(str), [&](auto c){
    return (str.rdbuf()->in_avail() ? "-" : "") + std::to_string(c);
});
```