# I don't want a comma after the last number/value, how do i remove it (c++, loop)

Tags: c++, loops

So, my friend's program is supposed to find the Multiplicative of Number three then print them out with a comma between the number. And not for the last one.

```
int a;
int b;

cout<< "First Number = ";
cin>>a;
cout<< "Last Number = ";
cin>>b;

if(a<=b)
{
    for(a;a<=b;a++)
    {
        if(a%3 == 0 && a%2 != 0)
        {   
            cout<<a;
        }
        if(a<b && a%3==0 && a%2 != 0)
        {
            cout<< " , ";
        }
        else if(a==b)
        {
            cout<< ".";
        }
    }
}
```

And after i input

a = 1

b = 20

this is what i expected

> 3 , 9 , 15.

and this is what i actually get

> 3 , 9 , 15 , .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing lists with commas C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496982/printing-lists-with-commas-c)

Comment: check if a==b before cout<<" , "

Comment: This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36137997/convert-vectorunsigned-char-1-2-3-into-string-1-2-3-as-digits/36138229#36138229

Comment: @V.Y.: `a==b` and `a<b` happen obviously in 2 different loops, so your suggestion won't solve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
char const* sep = ""; // item separator (nothing to begin with)

for(a;a<=b;a++)
{
    if(a%3 == 0 && a%2 != 0)
    {   
        cout << sep << a; // output the separator before the next value
        sep = ", "; // now change it to a comma
    }
}

cout << "."; // finish with a full stop
```

Comment: it gives me "Error 'sep' does not name a type" and "Error 'sep' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: @FcIp3 perhaps you are using an older version of the standard. I edited the code so it should hopefully work now.